# How to calcuate equal error rate based on predict_proba in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, biometrics

Let say, I used SVM from sci-kit learn to classify several biometric samples.

It will generate a probability estimate of genuine user and an imposter.

So, from here how do I calculate EER?

What I did so far

```
for threshold in range_iteration:
    far.append(np.size(np.where(score_imposter >= threshold)) / np.size(score_imposter))
    frr.append(np.size(np.where(score_genuine < threshold)) / np.size(score_genuine))
```

Please note that the threshold is defined based on the several intervals based on the largest and smallest values from predict_proba.

`score_genuine` is equal to the probability estimates from the genuine user based on the genuine test samples, focussing on the column of genuine probability. That's I wrote lower than the threshold as false rejection.

While `score_imposter` is the probability of predicting genuine users but with a score greater than the threshold since I assumed, greater than the threshold is considered as false acceptance.

Comment: Why you dont simply use model.predict ? if you wanna use predict_proba that badly just do np.argmax(model.predict_proba(x)) where x is the new input

Comment: I'm talking about EER in biometric